# Is there a way to declare multiple function parameters without declaring a type for each element, if they all have the same type?

Tags: c++

In other words, is there way to write this in a more sophisticated way?

```
double function(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4)
{
    //function body
}
```

Comment: Use an `std::array<double, 8>` or a `struct` if you want to keep a naming over the parameters.

Comment: as posted, no. if you have several closely related types, consider using a struct

Comment: Or `std::array<Point<double>, 4>` or whatever. The goal is to structure your data however makes the most sense, and having indices in variable names smells like missing structure.

Comment: Use a `template` and `...`

Comment: Why do you want to make it more sophisticated?